# Get all urls starting with http/https and ending with exe,msi,etc.. from tons of files and testing http response code and write output to a file

Tags: curl, types, grep, find, wget

I have a directory with tons of files. I want to get all URLs in the format:

```
http://********.exe
https://*******.exe
http:// *******.msi
https://**********msi
```

etc... etc..

And test the HTTP response code.
Finally, print output to a file like this:

```
200: https://downloads-global.3cx.com/downloads/3CXCallFlowDesigner.exe
200: https://downloads.3cx.com/downloads/3CXPhoneforWindows16.msi
302: https://github.com/3ll3d00d/beqdesigner/releases/download/0.9.5/beqdesignerSetup.exe
302: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases/download/v1.3.1/robo3t-1.3.1-windows-x86_64-7419c406.exe
200: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sauerbraten/files/sauerbraten/2020_11_29/sauerbraten_2020_12_21_windows.exe/download
200: https://storage.googleapis.com/images.abasky.net/119676df089a90ab3c3004398806433938052586dcd9a6bcacfb0e3e4024f339/2.2.672/abaclient-2.2.672-de.msi
200: https://www.abisource.com/downloads/abiword/2.9.4/Windows/abiword-setup-2.9.4.exe
302: https://github.com/Chit132/abyss-overlay/releases/download/v1.2.2/Abyss.Overlay.Setup.v1.2.2.exe
```

Comment: Can you provide the source files of these URLs?

Comment: The URLs are in the text files present inside the directories.

Comment: Add in question content of one such file